# How can I get all div elements with jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am learning how to use jsoup. I first thought jsoup was like jquery but it is not.

I want to extract this html body to elements of divs.

```
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
            <div>
                <h1>Title</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="/xx.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Paragraph 1</p>
                <p>Paragraph 2</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2><b>End</b></h2>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

I am using this code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
Elements divs = doc.select("div");
```

but it returns all of the divs. I want elements to return like this :

```
divs.get(0).toString(); // "<h1>Title</h1>"
divs.get(1).toString(); // "<img src="/xx.jpg" />"
divs.get(2).toString(); // "<p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p>"
divs.get(3).toString(); // "<h2><b>End</b></h2>"
```

Please assist me in getting divs to elements with jsoup and return as above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do divs.get(0).html();

It will give you the inner html of the tag

Answer (score 5):

Using [.html()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#html()) will retrieve an inner html.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
Elements divs = doc.select("div");
//divs.get(0).html();
for(Element elem : divs){
  System.out.println(elem.html()); //get all elements inside div
}
```

If you want to include div you can use [.outerHtml()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#outerHtml()).